# Como obtener los máximos registros de varios clientes en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas

estoy tratando de obtener los últimos pagos de varios clientes, pero no logro filtrarlos bien. He intentado con la siguiente consulta pero no funciona, también intente con subconsulta pero no logro obtener el resultado deseado. Dejo una imagen de lo que obtengo y de lo que quiero obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select distinct s.nroSocio, s.nombre, s.apellido, max(c.fechaPago)as 'Ultimo pago', c.estado
from Socios s join Cuotas c on s.nroSocio = c.nroSocio
group by  s.nroSocio, s.nombre, s.apellido, c.fechaPago, c.estado
order by 4 desc
```

Aca dejo las 2 tablas que utilizo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consulta que estoy utilizando, intente obtener la máxima fecha con una subconsulta con MAX y TOP, pero tampoco funciona. Seguro tengo un error conceptual, si me pudieran dar una mano seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: seria al ultimo poner el order by Ultimo_pago desc limit 2

Comment: Y al ordenamiento descendente de la columna que almacena la fecha dale un limit 2

Comment: Me exprese mal, yo corregi. En el ejemplo necesito esos 2 registros, pero en realidad no se cuantos van a ser los registros en la tabla de socios. Pueden aparecer mas, por eso no puedo usar el limit 2.

Comment: Danos la estructura de las tablas y datos de prueba para construir una respuesta

Comment: ¿necesitas la máxima fecha por socio sin importar el estado?

Comment: Exacto, necesito la maxima fecha sin tener en cuenta el estado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema parte de estar agrupado por `fechaPago` aunque el query iba bien encaminado, al agregar al `GROUP BY` dicho campo, perdias el resultado que necesitas, basicamente quitandolo obtendras el resultado, algo asi:

```
SELECT s.nroSocio,s.nombre,s.apellido,MAX(fechaPago) FECHA from socios s
INNER JOIN Cuotas c on s.nroSocio = c.nroSocio
GROUP BY s.nroSocio,s.nombre,s.apellido
```

Te dejo el ejemplo con el `DataSet` que probé, para que lo puedas comprobar.

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a37de16dee82570ac0b4b14f9234982a)</kbd>

Según lo que mencionaste en los comentarios, si quisieras obtener el estado que corresponde a la máxima fecha, podrias lograrlo con una subconsulta, asi:

```
SELECT *,(select TOP 1 ESTADO FROM Cuotas where nroSocio = x.nroSocio and fechaPago = x.ultimoPago) estado 
FROM (SELECT s.nroSocio,s.nombre,s.apellido,MAX(fechaPago) ultimoPago 
from socios s
INNER JOIN Cuotas c on s.nroSocio = c.nroSocio
GROUP BY s.nroSocio,s.nombre,s.apellido) x
```

Te dejo el también el ejemplo de esta consulta:

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e07828f7fb03fb1ede9b07f86548fef)</kbd>

Aunque aclaró que puede darte un problema en caso que existan 2 fechas similares y con estados diferentes, para evitar el error puse el `TOP 1` en la subconsulta, ojala te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Esto es lo que buscaba, yo pensé que tenia que poner la fecha de pago porque figuraba en el select, asumí que todo lo que esta en el select debe estar en el group by

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras lograr, pero que bueno que te sirvió, si puedes marcala como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: la ultima duda, al agregar el estado en el select y en el group by al ultimo me aparece otro registros que no deberia aparecer. Se debe a que agregue el estado???

Comment: @FrancoTorres lo que ocurre es que por cada estado habrá una fecha máxima, era lo que te comentaba de agregar o quitar campos del `GROUP BY`, puedes delimitar con `WHERE` para un estado determinado, pero si igual quieres saber cual es la fecha máxima y a que estado pertenece, se debe modificar el query y usar subconsultas, avisame y puedo modificar la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Si me haces el favor, porque necesito el estado también, pero la verdad que la subconsulta no me esta saliendo tampoco.

Comment: @FrancoTorres modifique la respuesta, espero que sea lo que buscabas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos maneras de hacerlo uno, y no creo que te funciones es un "Having", el cual se usa después del  group by y este sirve para filtrar los datos y quedaría algo asi:

```
select distinct s.nroSocio, s.nombre, s.apellido, max(c.fechaPago)as 'Ultimo pago', c.estado
from Socios s join Cuotas c on s.nroSocio = c.nroSocio
group by  s.nroSocio, s.nombre, s.apellido, c.fechaPago, c.estado having c.estado = Valida'
order by 4 desc
```

La segunda manera seria usando un "Where" asi:

```
select distinct s.nroSocio, s.nombre, s.apellido, max(c.fechaPago)as 'Ultimo pago', c.estado
from Socios s join Cuotas c on s.nroSocio = c.nroSocio
where c.estado = 'Valida'
group by  s.nroSocio, s.nombre, s.apellido, c.fechaPago, c.estado
order by 4 desc
```

Comment: No necesariamente, el having, filtra los datos agrupados(el dato que este en el having debe también estar incluido en el group by) , o de funciones agregadas (SUM, Max, etc.) , según la documentación de Microsoft

Comment: Ya agregue mas info para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), puede que me equivoque, aun así ya le especifique tambien con la clausula where